# New USB stick freezes processes that come in contact with it (dd, fdisk, gparted, etc)

Tags: boot, usb, usb-drive, fdisk, freeze

I bought a new USB stick to upgrade my os (debian) on my laptop. I used *gnome-multi-writer* to write the *.iso* file into the device. The writing process never showed a message of success or error so I decided to format the USB and start again.

I tried using the *gnome-disks* program to delete the partitions that were created by the multi-writer but was unsuccessful, same when trying with `fdisk`. I unfortunately don't remember the error messages.

I stopped trying to format the USB. When I tried to boot the new OS from it, I was able to access the welcome screen of Debian 11, but after clicking on "graphical install", it froze. **I rebooted my computer by long pressing the power button**. Ever since I did that:

Nautilus doesn't show my USB, trying to list it using `fdisk -l` results in the process hanging, same when trying to interact with it using `gparted`, same when trying to mount.

The system detects the USB, because `lsblk` results in the following:

```
NAME     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda        8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1     8:1    0  65.2G  0 part  /
├─sda2     8:2    0 391.2G  0 part  
│ └─home 254:1    0 391.2G  0 crypt /home
├─sda3     8:3    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5     8:5    0   9.4G  0 part  
  └─swap 254:0    0   9.4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb        8:16   0  14.9G  0 disk  
└─sdb1     8:17   0  14.9G  0 part  
sdc        8:32   1  28.9G  0 disk
```

This is what I get when I just plug it and run `dmesg`:

```
[ 3570.761381] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 3570.782121] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=dd35
[ 3570.782123] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3570.782124] usb 3-2: Product: ADATA USB Flash Drive
[ 3570.782126] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ADATA
[ 3570.782127] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 22A1712181510005
[ 3570.845430] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3570.845610] scsi host3: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 3571.895649] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ADATA    USB Flash Drive  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3571.896201] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3571.896333] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 60620800 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.9 GiB)
[ 3571.896456] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 3571.896459] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 3571.896574] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

Moments after plugging it in, the following log is printed a couple of times:

```
[ 3949.110909] usb 3-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
```

Until the next log appears:

```
[ 4111.067535] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4111.067550] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 4111.067552] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[ 4111.067556] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
```

Then both logs cycle indefinitely.

Is there a way to fix the problem? I'm lucky is not an expensive device. I feel like it broke when I turned my machine off after it froze when booting it. What do you think caused it? Do you think it was the multi-writer or it was me trying to delete/format partitions?

If you have a hypothesis please explain why these problems happen and how to avoid it in the future. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Plug the stick in, then try flashing it on command line `dd if=<installerfile>.iso of=/dev/sd<X> bs=1024 status=progress` - verify with `dmesg` the correct device <X>. I've created my installers with that for long time. Another tool I've had 100% success with is Balena Etcher.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.